# Can someone please tell me why this js function doesn't run on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've:

```
 //Resize tabs - height when window size changes. Don't forget to reset niceScroll
 function recalc_tab_height () {
    //
    var wrapper_h = $(".ui-panel-content-wrap").outerHeight();
    var content_h = $(".ui-content").outerHeight();
    var current_h = $(".tab1").outerHeight();
    var newHeight = (wrapper_h - content_h) + current_h;
    //
    $(".tab1, .tab2, .tab3").css({"height":newHeight}).getNiceScroll().resize();
 }
 //Run once onLoad
 recalc_tab_height();
```

That is supposed to resize lyrics section on-load to fit the screen. But it doesn't run at all... any ideas why? it is inside ui.js

http://mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/

Comment: if yu want to execute the function on load cal it like this `$(document).ready({recalc_tab_height();});`

Comment: Your DOM elements don't exist yet (at the time of the script execution), you can either do what Deepu suggested, or place your script file after the elements you're targeting.

Comment: @Deepu but it is already inside document.ready: http://mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/js/ui.js

Comment: Your function runs when you load your page. @SandroDzneladze

Comment: @Ashwin my function runs when document is ready

Comment: Yes, is there some other issue with it? @SandroDzneladze

Comment: This function is useless if your dom is not ready. It will always uncertain.

Comment: @Ashwin can you access this? http://mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/

Answer (score 6):

try

```
$(function() {
    recalc_tab_height();
});
```

instead of your last line.

`$(...)` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(...)` and is executed as soon as your page is entirely loaded, so that you can deal with `DOM` element properties.

Comment: but it is already inside document.ready: mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/js/ui.js

Comment: I cannot access your page or the js file. Maybe a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) would help.

Comment: Can you please try: http://idev.dyndns-at-home.com:800/mobile-radio/ matbe DNS server is misbehaving.

Comment: No, doesn't work. Maybe your code inside the function has errors. Can you show us some html?

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Hey, Rob, I uploaded it on live server for you. http://radio.idev.ge/ Can you please take a look?

Comment: Thanks, but everything seems to work fine in firefox. The div's are resized when I set a breakpoint into the function before `$(".tab1, .tab2, .tab3")...` and then execute the line manually.

Comment: It looks like chrome-jquery bug. I changed css() to animate() and it works.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the feedback. Please answer your own question and mark is as accepted answer. Maybe you should try a newer jquery version than 1.9.1 to get it working with `.css()` and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :** Need to set `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 //Run once onLoad
 recalc_tab_height();

});
```

Comment: but it is already inside document.ready: mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/js/ui.js

Comment: @SandroDzneladze you have added this ui.js inside your page correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

To load this function either you should use this on body as

```
<body onload="recalc_tab_height();" >
```

or by jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  recalc_tab_height();
});
```

Comment: but it is already inside document.ready: mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/js/ui.js

Comment: @SandroDzneladze you have added this ui.js inside your page correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the function call when the dom is ready.Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    recalc_tab_height();
});
```

Comment: but it is already inside document.ready: mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/js/ui.js

Comment: Have you checked whether the function call is happening.?Try with an `alert('inside function');` inside your function to check whether the funciton is getting called or not

Comment: Yes, all variables are also calculated correctly, what doesn't run is this: $(".tab1, .tab2, .tab3").css({"height":newHeight}).getNiceScroll().resize();

Answer (score 0):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "**ready**." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside **$(document).ready()** will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for **JavaScript** code to execute. Code included inside **$(window).load(function() { ... })** will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

So you have to call your function inside
 `$(document).ready({...});` or `$(window).load(function() { ... });`

Comment: but it is already inside document.ready: mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/js/ui.js

Answer (score 0):

I changed css() to animate() and it works.